# Did I calculate the inverse of this matrix correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I tried doing it in a different way than I normally do and I am not sure if it is correct. I looked it up [here](https://matrix.reshish.com/inverCalculation.php) and I know that even if it looks different it may still be the same matrix but it's hard to tell. Did I do it right?

[image]

Another question: if I had done it right and took the determinant of the inverse matrix I got and put the original one in that website and taken the determinant of the resulting one would they be the same? In other words, is the determinant basically a way of checking if two matrices are the same even if they look different because elementary operations don't change this determinant?

Comment: Determinant of inverse is inverse of determinant (if not zero)

Comment: 1) It doesn't seem quite finished. 2° Maxima yields a very different result, as far as I can read you rotated screenshot.

Comment: The inverse of a matrix $A$ (it it exists) is completely determined by $A$, so it's impossible for two matrices to be the inverse matrix of $A$ unless they are exactly identical (not just "look the same").  
About the last question: not all row operations leave the determinant unchanged, for example replacing a row by $c$ times that row will multiply the determinant by $c$.
In any case if two matrices have the same determinant, you cannot conclude that one is obtained from the other by row operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second question, if two matrices are equal, then they have the same determinant. But the fact that two matrices have the same determinant does not imply that the matrices are equal.

Comment: I remember vaguely my professor saying that when you perform these operations on a matrix it doesn't change the... was it the characteristic of the matrix and not the determinant?

Comment: That is true, performing those operations does not change the determinant. But you were asking if you could use the determinant to check if the matrices were equal and you cannot do that. I mean, if you have that two matrices have different determinant, then you know for sure they are different. But the fact that two matrices have the same determinant does not imply that they are equal.

Comment: How do you check if two matrices are equal then when they look different?

Comment: Two matrices will only be equal if the elements which are in the same position are equal. You can transform those elements until it is clear whether they are equal or not.

Comment: I read that every matrix has a unique reduced echelon form. If I reduce two matrices that "look" different to the reduced echelon form and it's same same result does that mean they are equal then?

Comment: Think of the identity matrix (A) and the identity matrix multiplied by two (B). A is already in its reduced echelon form. As for B, if you divide each row by 2, you get its reduced echelon form which is the same as A's reduced echelon form. However, even though both matrices have the same reduced echelon form, A is not equal to B.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of matrix equivalence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) with the fact that two matrices are equal.

Answer (score -1):

What you have done is wrong. When you use Gauss' method for obtaining the inverse matrix, you can only do operations with **rows**, **not** with **columns** (not even changing two columns, which is what you did.)

Comment: Actually, you can also  have column operations, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear! I did not know.

Comment: You may use either because swapping rows for columns doesn't affect the determinant. However, you cannot use both together.

Comment: @Bernard I did not know that, thanks